# CodeIgniter with wordpress auto escaping post data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Somewhere along the line I must have enabled some what of an escaping command. I've gone through the config and nothing seems to stand out. I currently have  `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` and can't see where else the escaping is done.

I've created a blank controller

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $this->load->view('tinymce');
    }

}
```

and a pretty basic form data page

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url() . uri_string()?>">
    <textarea name="response"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

For some odd reason when ever I try to write a hyperlink using the `<a href="#"></a>` tags, the urls are always escaped, resulting in broken data.

Example: In the textarea I write `test <a href="http://test.com">test url</a>`, the post data dumps out `array (size=1)
  'response' => string 'test <a href=\"http://test.com\">test url</a>' (length=45)`

Which in returns ends up as http://example.com/http://test.com

I've removed all autoloaders but still get the same error. I also tried this on a fresh install of CI and was not able to reproduce it. If I enable `$config['global_xss_filtering']` the href ends up being deleted, resulting in `'test <a >test url</a>'`

Comment: I noticed your view is called tinymce, are you sure it's not a configuration problem there?

Comment: In my test script I'm not even using tinymce, so the problem is coming from a core file somewhere

Comment: I used CI for a long time and have never came across a problem as you described. There are only 2 places, from memory, that allow you to filter. 1st check the global_xss_filtering is set to false, then each of the post var using `$this->input->post("postVar1", false);` By default the second param of the post should already be false. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html for more information about the input class. Also it might be worth testing the JS/HTML front end because you are dumping the $_POST, which does not get effected by CI. Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm finding it extremely odd also, I've removed all helpers, libraries, headers, footers, pretty much everything and somehow it's still being manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably won't effect anyone else. With Code Igniter, I'm also running an integrated Wordpress, where in the root `index.php` I'm including the `wp-load.php` file. For some reason Wordpress is modifying all post data. Removing Wordpress load fixes the problem.

The solution to fix this is in `wp-settings.php` there is a call to `wp_magic_quotes();` which modifies the global POST and GET data. Comment this out and your problems go away.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, it is an odd thing running the two combined so I doubt it.